# Drawing a triangular array with a nested \foreach loop in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a triangular array of dots with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,5} {
  \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\x} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (.25);
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This compiles fine, but the output has an extra dot (probably because TikZ parses "{1,2,...,1}" as "{1,2}"):

```
        *
      * *
    * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

Does anyone know a systematic way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the interval of the loop is 1, you don't have to say `1,2,...,\x`. With just `1,...,\x` Ti*k*Z assumes that the interval is 1 and doesn't evaluate for 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {
  \foreach \y in {1,...,\x} {
    \draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (.25);
}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: That was easy.  Thanks!  For some reason I had gotten the impression that one always had to specify the interval explicitly.